# Unable to resolve "constants/categories.json" from "screens\GridFilter\GridFilter.js"

Tags: react-native

I'm new at react-native and trying to build an app. When I try to run my code I'm getting this error................................................................

> Failed building JavaScript bundle. Unable to resolve
> "constants/categories.json" from "screens\GridFilter\GridFilter.js"

GridFilter.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import categories from 'constants/categories.json';
import filterIcons from 'components/Icons/filterIcons';

import { isIphoneX } from 'utils';
import fonts from 'theme/fonts';

const formatData = (data, numColumns) => {
  const numberOfFullRows = Math.floor(data.length / numColumns);

  let numberOfElementsLastRow = data.length - numberOfFullRows * numColumns;
  while (numberOfElementsLastRow !== numColumns && numberOfElementsLastRow !== 0) {
    data.push({ key: `blank-${numberOfElementsLastRow}`, empty: true });
    numberOfElementsLastRow++;
  }

  return data;
};

const numColumns = 3;
const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

function GridFilter({ navigation: { navigate } }) {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    if (item.empty === true) {
      return <View style={[styles.item, styles.itemInvisible]} />;
    }
    const Icon = filterIcons[item.icon];
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => navigate('SearchTopBarStack')}>
        <View style={styles.iconWrapper}>
          <Icon width={50} height={50} color="#9f9f9f" />
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={formatData(categories, numColumns)}
        style={styles.wrapper}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        numColumns={numColumns}
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 150 }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
export default GridFilter;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    paddingTop: isIphoneX ? 40 : 20,
  },
  wrapper: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  iconWrapper: {
    margin: 10,
  },
  item: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    height: WIDTH / numColumns, // approximate a square
    padding: 20,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3',
    margin: 5,
  },
  itemInvisible: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  itemText: {
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: fonts.REGULAR,
  },
});
```

I tried to delete node modules and rebuild. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to your current directory or file in your import. Try to use './' or '../' when you import path. If you use vscode it will give you auto completions.

Answer (score 0):

"../../" is worked for me.

Comment: Please include more information like where this should be added or what should be changed to this.